# How to capture value from one layer that is assigned to field in data collection field using QField?

Tags: qfield

I am collecting attribute information for dead trees in a data collection layer (Tree_Loc) using QField.  When I create a new tree point I would like to have automatic assignment of the parcel number from the parcel layer to attribute “APN”in the Tree_Loc layer.

Answer (score 1):

Right click Tree_Loc layer. Got to Properties_Attribute form. Select "APN" and go to default settings. In there try

```
overlay_intersects('myparcellayername', APN )[0]
```

Comment: Thank you!  That was simple.